# .htaccess to IIS

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, iis, web-config

```
<filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4|woff|eot|svg|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
Header set Expires "Sun, 17 July 2022 20:00:00 GMT"</filesMatch>
```

The above tag is from an .htaccess file from a laravel application.
This does ***not*** work for me even on the laravel application **with Apache**.Although this is not the problem i am trying to solve. What i am trying to achieve is recreate the same lines of configuration on an ***IIS web.config file.***

Does anyone have any idea? 
*The above file seems to be working with php artisan.*

I have tried some online converters but none of these accept these lines.

**I get the following error.**

The tag filesMatch is ok.
And then it prints this.

**The header set is not recognizable**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I used in IIS for cache control and works well now :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
       //choose 1 from this clientCache
       <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
            OR
       <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As i know, IIS doesn't supported .htaccess code. CMIIW